# How should I model that some instances cannot be modified?

Tags: core-data, uml, datamodel, data-modeling

I'm creating a data model using xcode and core data. It's an object graph, not entity-relationship model, so I have inheritance and many-to-many relationships.

This is my problem:
I have a class or entity called Category. Some categories are created by the app and cannot be deleted or modified by the user. Users can create their own categories.

After thinking about it, I found 4 ways to model this. See the picture:

[image]

I guess the most practical solution is just adding a flag, isSystemCategory, but I wonder what is the best solution from a modeling point of view. I guess the first one. An abstract class called Category, and 2 descendants, UserCategory which is editable and deletable, and SystemCategory, which is inmutable, users cannot delete it or modify. Note that descendantsdo not add any attribute, relationship or any change, so, that's the reason of my question. Is this a correct approach for a modeler?

I would like to know your ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on description I'd probably go for the first one too.

> Note that descendants do not add any attribute, relationship or any
>   change

But the behaviour is different.  And there's a logical difference too.  There is an implied 'relationship' between User and UserCategory that allows a User to create/update/delete a UC.  You may not need to hold this explicitly but it's there nonetheless (and you might capture it e.g. if you want to record who created/modified/deleted the category).

Creating separate subtypes will prevent a fair bit of nasty conditional logic that would otherwise crop up if you used e.g. a flag.  Think of deletion: with a flag you'd have an `if (category.isUserCategory) then <delete> else <...etc...>`.  Furthermore that logic would be replicated for each operation that behaves differently for user- vs. system categories.  Using subtypes removes that: `UserCategory.delete()` just does it, `SystemCategory.delete()` just doesn't (there might not even be a public delete on SystemCategory).  No conditionality.

One final thought: the problem here is really about authorisation.  If dealing with categories is the only place it comes up, then your option (1) is probably a pragmatic solution (the 'simplest thing that could possibly work').  If you have a recurring need to control access however, you probably should use a more general authorisation mechanism.

hth.

Comment: Fantastic reply. "Creating separate subtypes will prevent a fair bit of nasty conditional logic" that is exactly what I thought. However, I wonder if using core data (Category in the first case is an abstract class/entity) I can send request like: "All recipes that belongs to this category (that is, for both, user or system categories)" and the opposite, "recipes that belong to categories that were created by user". I think is possible, but not sure. Thanks a lot BTW.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm not familiar with Core Data specifically. However, I'd be very surprised if you couldn't ask for each of (a) all System Categories (instances of System Category), (b) all User Categories (instances of User Category) and (c) all Categories (instances of Category).  Category may be Abstract - but there are still instances of it at runtime (every {User|System}Category instance is simultaneously a Category instance).   hth.